# After Zooming Imageview canvas draw position changed how to fix it

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

the community I need help for I wrote some code for my android application. it's an android application for drawing over the image with zoom in and zoom out, I find some code from the internet I used that and build the application. but I got some problem that when I'm zooming image the canvas coordination was misplaced form position

Complete project on git
https://github.com/fayyaztech/android-canvas-zoom-and-draw-over-image

[picture 1 without zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQwRm.png)
[picture 2 after zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Ru9.png)
MainActivity

```
package com.example.fayyaztech.testzoom;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button enableZoomBtn;
    private DrawableView drawbleView;
    private CustomImageView touchImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawbleView = findViewById(R.id.drawble_view);
        enableZoomBtn = findViewById(R.id.enable_zoom);
        touchImageView = findViewById(R.id.zoom_iv);
        enableZoomBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        drawbleView.setDrawingEnabled(false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.enable_zoom:
                if(enableZoomBtn.getText().equals("disable zoom")){
                    touchImageView.setZoomEnable(false);
                    drawbleView.setDrawingEnabled(true);
                    enableZoomBtn.setText("enable zoom");
                } else{
                    touchImageView.setZoomEnable(true);
                    drawbleView.setDrawingEnabled(false);
                    enableZoomBtn.setText("disable zoom");
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

DrawableView code

```
package com.example.fayyaztech.testzoom;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

class DrawableView extends View {
    public int width;
    public  int height;
    private boolean isEditable;
    private Path drawPath;
    private Paint drawPaint;
    private Paint canvasPaint;
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    private int paintColor = Color.RED;

    public DrawableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        setupDrawing();
    }
    public DrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        this.height = h;
        this.width = w;
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }
    private void setupDrawing() {
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setDither(true);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }
    public void setDrawingEnabled(boolean isEditable){
        this.isEditable = isEditable;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(isEditable){
            float touchX = event.getX();
            float touchY = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                    drawPath = new Path();
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        } else{
            return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Custom Image View

```
package com.example.fayyaztech.testzoom;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
    Matrix matrix;
    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    private boolean zoomEnable= true;
    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 5f;
    float[] m;

    int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    protected float origWidth, origHeight;
    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;
    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    Context context;
    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }
    public void setZoomEnable(boolean status){
        zoomEnable = status;
    }
    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(zoomEnable){
                    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            last.set(curr);
                            start.set(last);
                            mode = DRAG;
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            if (mode == DRAG) {
                                float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                                float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                                float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                                        origWidth * saveScale);
                                float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                                        origHeight * saveScale);
                                matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                                fixTrans();
                                last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                            }
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            mode = NONE;
                            int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                            int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                            if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                                performClick();
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            mode = NONE;
                            break;
                    }

                    setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    invalidate();
                    return true; // indicate event was handled

                } else{
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                    || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                        viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                        detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
                * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        //
        // Rescales image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;
        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {
            // Fit to screen.
            float scale;

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                    || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;
            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                    - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                    - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }
}
```

And MainActivity Layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enable_zoom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="disable zoom"/>

    <com.example.fayyaztech.testzoom.CustomImageView
        android:id="@+id/zoom_iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/draw"
        android:layout_below="@+id/enable_zoom" />

    <com.example.fayyaztech.testzoom.DrawableView
        android:id="@+id/drawble_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/zoom_iv"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/zoom_iv" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I see no difference between the two screenshots

Comment: I see no difference between the two screenshots

Comment: I actually the same image uploaded twice please check this now. and help me to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I see you use canvas.save(), but no canvas.restore()...
Usually, it should be like:

canvas.save()
...
here your transformations on the canvas etc
...
canvas.restore()